# Linux. Как поднять cinnamon и драйвера nvidia не потерять?

Tags: linux, debian, видео, драйвер, nvidia

После установки `nvidia-glx`(драйвер) cinnamon  работает в резервном режиме(чёрний экран, есть сообщение про перезапуск и работает только контекстное меню.  Запускаю `nemo` и браузер через консоль. Они работают но без крестиков закрытия, тем и панелей из  Cinn. нет).  Lightdm работает нормально.
Ставил вместо пакета glx ставить драйвер в формате *.run , но ничего не изменилось. Видеокарта `Nvidia GT 620M`.  Также есть встроенная графика от intel.
Перезапуск  cinnamon  и удаление настроек из папки  home не помогают.

os:  debian 8.1 (linux) x64

log xorg: http://pastebin.com/MSBEqcaC

Comment: логи x-сервера *xorg* сохраняются в файлах `/var/log/Xorg*`.

Comment: добавил лог xorg. спасибо.

Comment: *(EE) [drm] KMS not enabled* — либо решайте эту проблему, либо задавайте по поводу неё **новый** вопрос. а лучше, с моей точки зрения, пользоваться свободным драйвером *nouveau*, имеющимся во всех популярных дистрибутивах.

Comment: спасибо. буду думать..

Answer (score 1):

вам надо либо решить проблему с *kms*, о которой пишется в приведённом логе (*(EE) [drm] KMS not enabled*), либо воспользоваться свободной реализацией драйвера для видеокарт *nvidia* под названием *nouveau* (всё необходимое присутствует в репозитории).